# custom search bar on my custom homepage

Tags: javascript, html, search

I need to constantly search files such as smss.exe at http://www.winpatrol.com/db/pluscloud/.

Is there a way I can make a customized searchbar on my custom homepage that will do this for me?

So if I type smss into the search bar it will take me to http://www.winpatrol.com/db/pluscloud/smss.html

I tried in pure HTML with GET requests and can't find a way to do it. I was thinking maybe there is a Javascript way or something.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you already tried?

Comment: Sure. I tried something like this. `<div id="search">
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="http://www.winpatrol.com/db/pluscloud/" name="gsrc">
<fieldset class="search">
<input type="text" name="q" class="box" value=""/>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>`but of course that didn't work because it creates http://www.winpatrol.com/db/pluscloud/?q=smss when i searched for smss. I need a way to store the query when typed in, concat ".html" to the end of it and then concat it to this http://www.winpatrol.com/db/pluscloud/

Comment: @bizarrechaos what do you mean concat `.html` and `winpatrol.com/db/pluscloud` to it?

Comment: so Im thinking what i type in the search bar for example is "smss". it stores smss as a string, then concatenates .html to that makeing the string smss.html then it concatenates that string to winpatrol.com/db/pluscloud/ and the returns the website I wish to view which is http://www.winpatrol.com/db/pluscloud/smss.html

Comment: In other words. I want to be able to type in smss into a search box and go to http://www.winpatrol.com/db/pluscloud/smss.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this is pure Javascript and will work, but if the user enters a non-existent page on that site, it will just lead to their not found page.

You could use server side PHP or something similar to achieve this in a better way.

Here is the JS solution with little error checking:

```
<form onsubmit="return redirect()">
    <input id="search_form_input" type="text" name="query" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect()
    {
        var query = document.getElementById('search_form_input').value;
        if (query != '') {
            window.location = 'http://www.winpatrol.com/db/pluscloud/' + query + '.html';
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I know it can be done in PHP, and I know PHP. But this is just a custom homepage for my personal use, its not on a server so PHP would be a little excessive. Thank you very much drew

Comment: You're welcome, I understand.  Since its just for personal use you know what to expect.  Glad to help.

Answer (score -1):

[Google custom search](http://www.google.com/cse/) is what you're probably looking for.

Comment: Why would you think that? the question is about using something like javascript to make a simple search form. Google custom search is far too cumbersome for something this simple and it's overkill. "I want to be able to type in smss into a search box and go to winpatrol.com/db/pluscloud/smss.html"